# Can not deploy from maven after deploying using CLI on JBOSS

Tags: maven, jboss

On our jenkins we have a build pipe that as a last step deploys the artifact (ear file in this case) to a remote JBoss 6.4 server. This works fine as long as I don't install that same ear file using tje JBoss cli on the server. After that Maven complains:

```
Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven- 
plugin:7.7.Final:deploy (deploy) on project caretrack-ear: 
Deployment failed and was rolled back. "JBAS018785: There is 
already a deployment called foo-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear with the 
same runtime name foo.ear"
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

Apparently as we build the assembly, used with the manual deploy, the ear file has a different name than the ear file built in the continuous integration pipe. Both try to deploy, different name but same runtime name.

The ear in the Assembly contained an ear with the version number still attached, while the ear in the ci-pipe had it's version number stripped.